# What is the probability that at least 2 people in class have the same birthday?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The title states the full question I was provided with. Am I able to just *assume* the class contains **more than** 12 students? If so, would we just do:

> (n ***choose*** 2?);  where n = number of students in class?

If not, how else could I go about this? Do I need to break it into more than 1 case? I know the solution is *probably* very simple, I just don't know if I am thinking about this in the right manner.

Comment: This is called [the birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). The wiki page contains the information you need.

Comment: "Am I able to just assume the class contains more than 12 students?" - Now why would you ever assume that??? If anything, you may want to assume "more than $1$ student" (otherwise, obviously, the probability is $0$). In order to find the general formula for $n$ students, calculate $1$ minus the probability of the **complementary** event: $1-\frac{365!}{(365-n)!\cdot365^{n}}$. BTW, with $n=23$, the probability is just a little over $50\%$, which is why this is generally referred to as the *Birthday Paradox* (considered a paradox because people normally expect a lot more than $23$ here).

Comment: You assume the class has n students an's express the answer in terms of n.  If you assume n=12 you will get a precise number.  If you assume n=20 you will get another.  Not sure where you got 12 from.

Comment: n choose 2 isn't the answer by the way.  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This image should answer your question.

[image]